# Creating <select> element and append data to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html5

I've made the following and have a few questions:

1. Do I have some (big) mistakes in this approach? (bad practices, 'this code is trash'...)

   1.1 If I do, can you suggest what to fix?
2. Are appended element created in good way?
3. Code in success function seems to be a little long.  Any way to refactor?

[image]

**CSS code**

```
.no-display-table {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="row">
    ...
    <!-- empty div will hold <select> which will be crated on ajax success --> 
    <div class="append-select col-md-3"></div>
    ...
</div>
...
<!-- onLoad => 'display: none', <tr> will be dynamically crated on Ajax Success -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
      <table id="options-table" class="table table-striped">
        <thead> <tr><th> Selected options </th></tr> </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
$(function() {
    $('#options-table').addClass('no-display-table');

    $('#product-option-select').change(function() {
        if($('.append-select select').length > 0) 
            $('.append-select select').remove();

        var selectedOptionId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '../option_types/' + selectedOptionId,
            success: function(data) {
                var element = '<select id="value-select" class="form-control">';
                element += '<option selected disabled>Select value...</option>';

                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    element += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>';
                }

                element += '</select>';
                $('.append-select').append(element);

                $('.append-select').on('change', '#value-select', function() {
                    $('#options-table').removeClass('no-display-table');

                    var selectedValue = $('#value-select option:selected').text();
                    var element = '<tr><td>' + selectedValue + '</td>';
                        element += '<td><a class="remove"> x </a></tr>';

                    $('#options-table tbody').append(element);

                    $('#options-table').on('mouseover', '.remove', function() {
                        $('.remove').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                    });

                    $('#options-table').on('click', '.remove', function() {
                        $(this).parent().parent().remove();

                        if($('#options-table tbody tr').length == 0)
                            $('#options-table').addClass('no-display-table');
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## My 2 cents:

- You could use `$().hide()` instead of assigning your custom hiding css class
- Similarly you could use `$().show()` instead of removing your custom hiding css class
- You do not have to check the length of a jQuery query, just call `remove()`, it will work.
- Your building of html inside the success callback is ugly, have a helper function to construct it and consider using DOM functions instead of HTML building. I personally tend to show/hide the select element and then rebuild the list with this helper function:

> ```
> function setOptions( id , array )
> {
>   //Get the element
>   var select = document.getElementById( id ) , i 
>   //Remove potentially existing children, somewhat heartless
>   while (select.firstChild)
>     select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
>   //Add the new children
>   for( i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ )
>   {
>     var element = new Option( array[i].id , array[i].name );
>     select.appendChild(element);        
>   }      
> }
> ```

- Assiging the listener in the success callback is also too much, consider building a listener that takes into account new elements on document instead `$(document').on('change',` etc.
- Same for the mouseover / click event listeners

Simply having the document element ( or any other parent element that stays in the DOM ) and the selector inside the on call should activate the listeners for new elements.

> ```
> function initializeListeners()
> {
>   $(document).on('change', '#value-select', function() {
>       $('#options-table').removeClass('no-display-table');
>
>       var selectedValue = $('#value-select option:selected').text();
>       var element = '<tr><td>' + selectedValue + '</td>';
>           element += '<td><a class="remove"> x </a></tr>';
>
>       $('#options-table tbody').append(element);
>
>       $('#options-table').on('mouseover', '.remove', function() {
>           $('.remove').css('cursor', 'pointer');
>       });
>
>       $('#options-table').on('click', '.remove', function() {
>           $(this).parent().parent().remove();
>
>           if($('#options-table tbody tr').length == 0)
>               $('#options-table').addClass('no-display-table');
>       });
>   });
> }
> ```

Comment: Assiging the listener in the success callback is also too much....Same for the mouseover / click event listeners

Can you please provide code for that?